# Wordpress: save object with protected attributes to transient will fail

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, serialization, transient

I want to save a custom object into a WordPress transient using [`set_transient( $name, $object, $expiration )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/). My object contains *protected* attributes.

**Problem**: this function returns true but there is no value set into database.

I figured out that [php's `serialize` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) use null bytes on private and protected members:

> Object's private members have the class name prepended to the member name; protected members have a '*' prepended to the member name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

Apparently these null bytes break mysql queries like this one: `update wp_options set option_value="Test data \0*\0 nothing will be set" where option_name='test';`

How can I avoid this behavior ?